# Seemingly simple MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

Here is what my tables look like:

```
CREATE TABLE Author(
authorID INT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE book(
ISBN INT PRIMARY KEY,
title VARCHAR(30),
authorID INT,
inventory INT,
paperBack BOOLEAN,
fiction BOOLEAN,
FOREIGN KEY (authorID) REFERENCES Author(authorID)
);
```

I need to find out which author has written the most books.
I am working with a mixture of the following. I guess I am having trouble piecing it all together...

```
  SELECT authorID, count(*) 
    from book 
group by authorID;
```

I am not sure how to get the single row that has the highest count and then only get the authorID of that row. Once I have that authorID, I know how to get the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is the ID of the author, then use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1` as others have pointed out.  However, if you're going to want other fields from Author, *or* if you are interested in multiple authors (second highest count, lowest count, etc), then you should consider joining to a derived table, like this:

```
SELECT Author.*, d1.book_count
FROM Author
  JOIN (SELECT authorID, count(authorID) as book_count FROM book GROUP BY authorID) d1
  ON Author.authorID = d1.authorID
ORDER BY 
  d1.book_count
```

Would give a result set like this:

```
 +----------------------------------+
 | AuthorID  |  Name  |  book_count |
 +----------------------------------+
 | 1         | bob    | 20          |
 | 9001      | sam    | 18          |

 ...
```

Comment: yes although at the cost of readability.  Great for certain situations though.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select a.name,count(*)
from author a
join book b on b.authorID=a.authorID
group by a.Name
order by 2 desc
limit 1
```

Comment: What is the'order by 2' for? is 2 just the second returned value?

Comment: the number 2 refers to the second column in the result set

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a subquery, you can just do something like this:

`SELECT authorID FROM book GROUP BY authorID ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1`

this should give you the authorID of the author with the most books.

Comment: notice that it is also possible to return the author name directly as in @Sparky  solution, if that is what you want.